# Getting Summation from a Table, with matching values from another Table in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have 2 tables created in Excel, which are identical in structure and the column and row names.

The only difference is that the first table has data (for the effort in work days) in it while the second is a reference table stating which milestone each cell belongs to. A sample of these tables is:

TBL1:

```
|    | App1 | App2 | App3 |
| T1 |  32  |  12  |  48  |
| T2 |  40  |  16  |  30  |
| T3 |  56  |  18  |  36  |
```

TBL2:

```
|    | App1 | App2 | App3 |
| T1 |  1   |  2   |  3   |
| T2 |  2   |  1   |  2   |
| T3 |  1   |  1   |  1   |
```

I want to collate these values so that I get SUM of 1, 2 and 3

```
|    | Days Summation   |
| 1  |  =32+56+16+18+36 |
| 2  |  =40+12+30       |
| 3  |  =48             |
```

So basically, want to find:

```
IF(COL_VAL_IN_TBL2=1) THEN SUM ALL VALUES IN TBL1 CORRESPONDING TO THE ROW-COL IN RESPECTIVE
```

Is it possible to get a formula which I can use to do this without using something like a Pivot Table?

Comment: I totally don't get it. How are you getting `=32+56+16+18+36` and those other summations? Can you explain that part better. `Collate` and `Corresponding to the row-col` isn't doing it for me. Perhaps I'm just slow this morning.

Comment: @JNevill So I have just actually summed up the corresponding cell in the Table 1 corresponding to the cell in Table 2. If Table2 contains 1 in any cell, then the corresponding cell in Table1 needs to be added as a cumulative.

Comment: Basically for any common values in Table2, I want to SUM all the corresponding cell in Table1, for which the values in Table2 are the same. Hope that makes sense? :-)

Comment: OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOH  Yea... ok I get it. Man... I was really scratching my head trying to figure that one out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sumif()` to do this:

[image]

Here it's just looking at `table2` values and comparing them to your `1`, `2`, or `3` and then summing the corresponding cells from your `table1`

Answer (score 1):

`SUMIF` will do the trick if I understand correctly:

If you put 1 in A1, then 2 in A2, etc. Then enter in B1`=SUMIF(TBL2Range,A1,TBL1Range)` and copy down. Where `TBL2Range` is the address of your table.